# Why page is reloading though I used router in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am learning **router**. In a basic project, I am applying **routes**. But every time I click on a component the page gets reloaded. I don't understand why it is happening.

Here is my codes:

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Shop from './components/Shop/Shop';
import Review from './components/Review/Review.jsx';
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CartProvider } from './contexts/CartContext';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CartProvider>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
          <Route path="/review" element={<Review />} />
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={
              <main style={{ padding: '1rem' }}>
                <p>There's nothing here!</p>
              </main>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </CartProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Versions I am using:**

```
"react": "^17.0.2"
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2"
```

What is the problem and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is being clicked upon? Are you clicking links in a nav section somewhere? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. I was clicking the <a> tag on the navbar. I changed it to <Link> and now it is working.

Comment: Bingo.  Yeah, raw anchor tags will do that. Glad you got it sorted out. Voted to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers and good luck.